# Why does this initializer_list use misbehave when passing strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdinitializerlist

I've tried the C++0x initializer-list implementation of my G++ version but it outputs only empty lines.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::initializer_list<std::string> a({"hello", "stackoverflow"});
  for(auto it = a.begin(), ite = a.end(); it != ite; ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're creating two initializer lists in the example above. Temporary `{"hello", "stackoverflow"}` and `std::initializer_list<std::string> a`.

On gcc, `{}` initializer lists are in fact temporary arrays whose lifetime ends after full statement (unless bound directly to `std::initializer_list` like in the commented line in the example below).

The lifetime of internal array of the first list ends right after `a`'s constructor returns and thus `a`'s array now points to invalid memory (gcc only copies the pointer). You can check, that `std::string` destructors get called before you enter the loop.

And when you get to loop, you're reading invalid memory.

According to lastest standard draft (n3242), §18.9/1, initializer lists cannot be even copied like that (they provide no constructor with parameters).

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A(int)
  { }

  ~A()
  {
    std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::initializer_list<A> a({A(2), A(3)});
  // vs std::initializer_list<A> a{A(2), A(3)};
  std::cout << "after a's construction" << std::endl;
}
```

With gcc 4.5.0, I get

```
dtor
dtor
after a's construction
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::initializer_list<std::string> a({"hello", "stackoverflow"});
```

If I declare that as:

```
std::initializer_list<std::string> a{"hello", "stackoverflow"}; //without ()
```

then it's working : http://ideone.com/21mvL

But that is weird. Looks like its a compiler bug.

---

EDIT:

Its most certainly a compiler bug, because if I write `(*it).c_str()` it prints the strings!!

```
std::initializer_list<std::string> a({"hello", "stackoverflow"}); //with ()
for(auto it = a.begin(), ite = a.end(); it != ite; ++it)
   std::cout << (*it).c_str() << std::endl;
```

Code : http://ideone.com/hXr7V

Comment: @Johannes: If you remove `c_str()`, it doesn't print `"hello"` : http://ideone.com/NTRUh  ... and I'm confused. What is wrong with it?

Comment: It's because you're working with reference to local variable (which goes out of scope when the function returns). When you use c_str(), you're just lucky (or unlucky, depending on point of view) that the memory still contains reference to the `char*` string and that heap area hasn't been overwritten yet. :)